# Oraclize with private blockchain - generate custom address for OAR

Tags: solidity, contract-development, oracles

I am new to Oraclize. I am integrating a private blockchain with Oraclize. It says in the ethereum bridge document

> Add `OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(EnterYourOarCustomAddress);` to your
>   contract constructor, example:
>
> Where EnterYourOarCustomAddress is the address resolver generated when
>   you have run the script.

I ran the script

```
node bridge -H localhost:8042 -a 1
```

It prints

> WARN Using 'account address' to query contracts on your blockchain,
>   make sure it is unlocked and do not use the same address to deploy
>   your contracts

Please note, I wrote the account address in quote for the address in -a 1.
Is this also the custom OAR address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marco from Oraclize here. By default the most recent version of the Ethereum Bridge automatically deploys in your private blockchain the Oraclize Address Resolver and the Oraclize Connectors, which are two contracts used by Oraclize to interact with your contract. You don't need to include the OAR in your contract constructor.

If the configuration is correct, the Ethereum-Bridge should log "INFO deploying the address resolver with a deterministic address..." in the command line. 
The address specified when you launch the bridge is only used to deploy the OAR and the connector, it is not the address of the OAR. You just shouldn't use it to deploy your contract. I have responsed to your question?

Comment: When I started the node bridge, I got the info [2017-07-31T23:59:18.253Z] INFO you are running ethereum-bridge - version: 0.5.4
[2017-07-31T23:59:18.254Z] INFO saving logs to: ./bridge.log
[2017-07-31T23:59:18.254Z] INFO using active mode
[2017-07-31T23:59:18.254Z] INFO Connecting to eth node http://localhost:8042
[2017-07-31T23:59:19.185Z] INFO connected to node type Geth/miner1/v1.6.7-unstable-a0aa071c/darwin-amd64/go1.8.3
[2017-07-31T23:59:19.631Z] INFO deploying the oraclize connector contract...
It did not comment about deploying the address resolver.

Comment: You were right. When I start mining, it prints the OAR address. Thanks