# Oraclize bridge with private blockchain, deterministic OAR disabled

Tags: go-ethereum, oracles

I created a geth console with

```
geth --datadir /Users/test/data/privateEthereum --networkid 42 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8042" --port "30303" --maxpeers 3 --nat=any --rpccorsdomain \"*\"  --unlock "0,1" --password /Users/test/data/privateEthereum/password.txt console
```

and started the miner

When I started the bridge with

```
node bridge -H localhost:8042 -a 1
```

I get

> Please wait...
>
> [2017-11-03T17:22:51.822Z] INFO you are running
>   ethereum-bridge - version: 0.5.5
>
> [2017-11-03T17:22:51.823Z] INFO
>   saving logs to: ./bridge.log
>
> [2017-11-03T17:22:51.823Z] INFO using
>   active mode
>
> [2017-11-03T17:22:51.823Z] INFO Connecting to eth node
>   http://localhost:8042
>
> [2017-11-03T17:22:53.256Z] INFO connected to
>   node type Geth/v1.7.2-stable-1db4ecdc/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2
>
> [2017-11-03T17:22:53.885Z] WARN Using
>   0x974e5ce3d49bacb3d6d47b827e12972940fb764d to query contracts on your
>   blockchain, make sure it is unlocked and do not use the same address
>   to deploy your contracts
>
> [2017-11-03T17:22:54.025Z] INFO deploying the
>   oraclize connector contract...
>
> [2017-11-03T17:23:04.410Z] INFO
>   connector deployed to: 0x879db369b9b06260c59e7123f2d9dd650353a689
>
> [2017-11-03T17:23:05.705Z] WARN deterministic OAR disabled/not
>   available, please update your contract with the new custom address
>   generated
>
> [2017-11-03T17:23:05.706Z] INFO deploying the address
>   resolver contract...
>
> [2017-11-03T17:23:16.482Z] INFO address resolver
>   (OAR) deployed to: 0xabd00b99c13644df9f0b5c2f91ea3f718615e075
>
> [2017-11-03T17:23:16.482Z] INFO updating connector pricing...
>
> [2017-11-03T17:23:26.730Z] INFO successfully deployed all contracts
>
> [2017-11-03T17:23:26.735Z] INFO instance configuration file saved to
>   /Users/test/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/config/instance/oracle_instance_20171103T102326.json

How do I correct this?

> WARN deterministic OAR disabled/not available

There must be a mistake in my configuration. Any suggestions?

Comment: that's just a warning. Having you tried using `OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0xabd00b99c13644df9f0b5c2f91ea3f718615e075);`  as first line of your contract's constructor.

Comment: It is more than a warning. My contract is not able to access the web. As you suggested, when I add the OAR statement in my contract, it works fine. However, Oraclize tells that I do not have to write that  in my contract. See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23301/oraclize-with-private-blockchain-generate-custom-address-for-oar

Comment: I am not very sure about the Marco's answer, have not tried that personally. I used Oraclize long ago and then there we need to include the OAR in contract's constructor.

Comment: If we close the node-bridge, then  OAR will disappear...Is that means for next time deploying the contract we have to add new OAR to contract constructor? Is there any solution for OAR address keeps same in privateNet like testnet?

Answer (score 1):

There is no wrong, it is just a warning,you just need to put your OAR address in your contract constructor.
I think you may encounter some problem when using ethereum-bridge, and i have a look at your command to satrt your private network, and it's the command that causes problem.

The oraclize(ethereum-bridge) is only supported the `dev`chain , which means you should start your private network using geth like

```
geth --networkid 15 --datadir ./data --rpc --rpcapi "admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,txpool,web3" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --dev
```

or simply, you can start you your private network using

```
geth --dev --rpc console
```

- if you deploy the contract using ethereum-bridge on `Non-dev` private network, you will get gas error like

```
gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction in private network
```

so, all the problem is caused by `Non-dev`private network!
Good luck for you!

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same work like you, and got the OAR WARNING,
the oraclize-support in the oraclize gitter said that if you use ethereum-bridge on the mainnet, OAR is not needed, but it has to be add to the constructor of your contract if it's on private chain.Hope this helps.